# How to set MSS in netty io library

Tags: netty

TCP option MSS is not present in the channelconfig, I am trying to create a server socket with the a lower mss value, but that option is not found in the netty library, is this option available in the library.

Answer (score 0):

Its not exposed as java.nio and java.io not expose it as well. That said we may could expose it in our native transport if there is enough demand. Consider opening a feature request in netty.